# Direct sum of matrix function

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

This struct allows representing arbitrary size matrices, where M is the number of rows, N is the number of columns and data is a pointer to M*N values of type double stored by rows.

```
struct matrix {
    size_t M, N;
    double *data;
};


struct matrix *mat_directsum(const struct matrix *a, const struct matrix *b);
```

The function **mat_directsum** accepts two pointers to arrays as a parameter and should return to the direct sum, dynamically allocated on the heap.

Example:
[image]

```
A.M = 2
A.N = 3 
A.data = (1, 1, 2, 0, 1, -3)
```

Example of direct sum function

[image]

I just need a few tips on how to set the function, just to see how others work with arrays of this type, because the only way that comes to mind is an iterative methods with many loops, however, it is enough work long and ingenious, I would like to know if there are easier method to solve it. Thank you

ps.
(memory allocation is not a problem of course)

**EDIT**
I solved like that:

```
struct matrix *mat_directsum(const struct matrix *a, const struct matrix *b) {
    struct matrix *c = malloc(sizeof(struct matrix));
    c->M = a->M + b->M;
    c->N = a->N + b->N;
    int n = c->M * c->M;
    double *dati = calloc(n, sizeof(double));

    int t = 0;//index new array
    int y = 0;//index first mat
    int z = 0;//index second mat
    for (int i = 0; i < c->N; i++) {
        if (i < a->N) {//first mat
            for (int j = 0; j < c->M; j++) {
                if (j < a->M) {
                    dati[t] = a->data[y];
                    y++;
                }
                t++;
            }
        } else {//second mat
            for (int j = 0; j < c->M; j++) {
                if (j >= a->M) {
                    dati[t] = b->data[z];
                    z++;
                }
                t++;
            }
        }
    }
    c->data = dati;
    return c;
}
```

I don't know how to do it which only one for loop

Comment: `.... with many loops`. Hmmm, two nested for-loops should be enough. `for(i=0; i<(a.M+b.M); ++i) { for(j=0; j<(a.N+b.N); ++j) { if (.....`

Comment: what about the if condiction ?

Comment: In the `if` part you will compare `i` and `j` with the size of the original matrices to decide whether you shall write a zero or you should take a value from the one of the input matrices. Perhaps like `if (i < a.M) { ....`

Comment: Another approach could be `calloc` and a single `for`-loop where you used `memcpy` inside the loop. I suggest that you try to write some code and then update your question with that code (if you have problems with it). I'll like to help but I won't write all the code for you.

Comment: There is nothing special about this. There are actually bettwe approaches, including using a 2D array or a FAM.But what is your **specific** question? We are not a discussion site.

Comment: `int n = c->M * c->M;` - one of those should be `c->N`

Comment: Yeah I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

```
//macro which will point to an element indexed at [xe][ye]
#define ELEMENT(data,rows,columns,xe,ye) (data+((xe)*(columns)+(ye)))

struct matrix
{
    size_t M, N;
    double *data;
};


//won't mind changing the return type from "struct matrix*" to "struct matrix"
struct matrix mat_directsum(const struct matrix *a, const struct matrix *b)
{
    int x;
    struct matrix res;
    res.M = a->M + b->M;
    res.N = a->N + b->N;

    //using calloc will set the memory to zero i.e all the bytes will be set to zero.
    res.data = (double*)calloc(res.M * res.N, sizeof(double));
    if(res.data == NULL)
    {
            return res;
    }

    for(x = 0; x < a->M; ++x)
    {
            memcpy(ELEMENT(res.data, res.M, res.N, x, 0), ELEMENT(a->data, a->M, a->N, x, 0), a->N * sizeof(double));
    }
    for(x = 0; x < b->M; ++x)
    {
            //note the offset by [a->M][a->N] while accessing elements of res.
            memcpy(ELEMENT(res.data, res.M, res.N, x + a->M, a->N), ELEMENT(b->data, b->M, b->N, x, 0), b->N * sizeof(double));
    }

    return res;
}


struct matrix res = mat_directsum(&a, &b);
if(res.data != NULL)
{
    free(res.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the error `n = c->M * c->M`, spotted by M.M (what a coincidence of Ms!), your solution has another error in the `for` loops: You confused the row and column numbers M and N - since the values are *stored by rows*, the outer loop has to be `for (int i = 0; i < c->M; i++)` and the inner loops have to be `for (int j = 0; j < c->N; j++)`, so all `M` and `N` in those loops (also in the `if`s) have to be swapped. Apart from that and the missing allocation error checks, your solution is fine.

> I don't know how to do it which only one for loop

If you want to see an alternative approach, here's one with a helper function to insert the matrices into the sum matrix:

```
#include <string.h>

void mat_insert(const struct matrix *s, struct matrix *d, int r, int c)
{   // copy source matrix s to destination matrix d at row r, column c
    for (int i = 0; i < s->M; i++)  // for each row
        memcpy(d->data+(r+i)*d->N+c, s->data+i*s->N, s->N*sizeof*s->data);
}

struct matrix *mat_directsum(const struct matrix *a, const struct matrix *b)
{
    struct matrix *c = malloc(sizeof *c);   if (!c) return NULL;
    c->M = a->M + b->M;
    c->N = a->N + b->N;
    int n = c->M * c->N;
    c->data = calloc(n, sizeof *c->data);   if (!c->data) return free(c), NULL;
    mat_insert(a, c, 0, 0);         // copy a to c at row 0, column 0
    mat_insert(b, c, a->M, a->N);   // copy b to c at row a->M, column a->N
    return c;
}
```